# Can't boot on my Linux anymore after changing boot order (dual boot windows/debian)

Tags: linux, lvm, partition, data-recovery

Some months ago, I changed my boot order to make my windows in first boot position. Since this day I can't boot on my linux anymore because I don't see it when i'm booting.

After some research I've found that the problem may come from the fact that i've installed my Linux partitions with LVM, which may not be a good idea on a dual boot. But i'm not sure of anything.

I did not try a lot of things cause i'm a bit a newbie, and i would love to get my linux content back without breaking it. The only things i've done is to look at my disk partitions to see if my linux was at least still there.

[image: disk partitions]

If someone knows how to handle this, or anything else!

Comment: Windows has the somber habit to replace the boot sector with its own during core updates. Could that be the case? You could try to enter the BIOS setup and see in the boot section if there is an alternative boot entry (that would load grub [supposedly]). Have a look at *refind* as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,  I'll have a look at it, it's probably what happened (I hope so) 
But in my memories I've already tried to re-install grub and it wasn't working, but as i said in my post i'm not a pro at all so maybe I did something wrong! I'll tell you if it's solved, thx again